# How to make the JOptionsPane (Without a panel) close the program with X

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

So I know that there are a lot of similar questions asked on this site and through the internet in general, but I have not been able to find the exact answer or one that satisfies what I want to accomplish.

I have multiple `JOptionPane`s within my program. All of these `JOptionsPane`s have a "X" in the top corner. Currently they function just the same as any other `JOptionPane`'s default button.

I want the program to exit if the user clicks the "X". With any other the other buttons the screen will close but with "X" I want to cause a `System.exit(0)` type of event.

I tried implementing this by using an `if` statement like:

```
int result = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, getPanel(),"Return Builder", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, 
                JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, options, "default");

        if(result==JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION){
            System.exit(0);
        }
```

but I find that the entire program exits regardless of which button the user clicks. Even if they click one of my other `JButton`s that has an action listener the program still quits. I'll post the more complete picture of this particular GUI:

```
public static void displayGUI(){//Method to display the GUI. 

        final JButton buttonCreate = new JButton("Create Return");
        final JButton buttonConfirm = new JButton("Confirm");

        buttonConfirm.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent ae){


                if(output.getSize()>0){
                    JOptionPane.getRootFrame().dispose();   
                }else if(verifyBatch==true){
                    JOptionPane.getRootFrame().dispose();
                }else if(verifyBatch==false && output.getSize()==0){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You haven't added any transactions to confirm" +
                            " and you have no previously completed batches!");
                }
            }           
        });

        buttonCreate.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent ae){

                if(verifyBatch==true){

                    initialScreenDecisions="NONE";//The user did not choose to add any entry details to the output list.
                    MainWriter.finishedCounter=true;//The boolean counter to trigger that the return is finished goes to true.
                    while(MainWriter.entryDetails.size()>0){//Removes all entry details from the input list.
                        MainWriter.entryDetails.remove(0);
                    }

                    while(output.size()>0){//Removes all entry details from the output list..
                        output.remove(0);
                    }

                    JOptionPane.getRootFrame().dispose();

                }else{

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "There are no completed batches!");     

                }
            }
        });

        //Creates a JOptionPane for the first GUI featuring 7 buttons and 2 lists..

        final Object[] options = new Object[] {buttonConfirm,buttonCreate};

        int result = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, getPanel(),"Return Builder", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, 
                JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, options, "default");

        if(result==JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION){
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
```

So from this example, how can I make the "X" and only the "X" exit the entire program? I have many other `JOptionsPane`s that I need to implement similar measures.

Comment: Afaik Closing the window by pressing [x] is the same as pressing the cancel button. You'd have to generate you're own JDialog to be able to determine the actual mechanism that the user used to close the window

Comment: So there is no way to logically say "If user clicks "X" close the program" without using something other than a JOptionsPane?

Comment: I've not dug through the JavaDocs, but I seem to recall [Cancel] and [x] are the same thing from the perspective of the `JOptionPane` API, you will need to create your own `JDialog` and add the `JOptionPane` to it if you want to know more information

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'd mark it complete but you didn't set it as an answer.

Comment: @MadProgrammer They are different return values: `YES_OPTION`,
`NO_OPTION`,
`CANCEL_OPTION`,
`OK_OPTION` and
`CLOSED_OPTION`.

Comment: @user1803551 I'm well aware it returns multiple options, I was also under the impression that under some conditions, it only returned two possible results `OK_OPTION` or `CANCEL_OPTION` depending on how you had it configured, but since I tend to only look for `OK_OPTION`, I've never really cared for much else

Comment: @MadProgrammer I'm well aware that you are well aware of the multiple return options :) I thought that without the API you thought that `CANCEL` and `CLOSE` are the same.

Comment: @user1803551 I was more under the impression that it simply used `CANCEL`, but since I only look for the "approved" option 99% of the time, I've never had an occasion to need to use `CLOSE` (or `CANCEL` that much)

Comment: Yes user it was more of a personal preference. I felt like the fact that the "x" button did the same as my "next" button looked unprofessional. If I was to create this project again I wouldn't use JOptionPanes but what is done is done and I'm not going back now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> with "X" I want to cause a `System.exit(0)` type of event.

First of all, the JVM will automatically exit after your last window (`JOptionPane`) closes. This is probably the reason for

> Even if they click one of my other `JButton`s that has an action listener the program still quits.

Secondly, users usually do not expect that closing a dialog will exist the program, think about it from a GUI design point of view. You usually have a parent `JFrame` and the dialogs supplement it, they are not the "driving force" of the GUI.

If I create a frame just to stop the auto-closing of the JVM, you will see that the `JOptionPane` does give different return values for pressing the "X" and for other options:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "AA");
    System.out.println(result);
    if (result == JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION)
        System.exit(0);
}
```